# Creating a textbox that will then send keys to another application (like an onscreen keyboard does)

Tags: java, vbscript

This is going to be a bit convoluted, and likely seem a bit pointless to many (if not all) of you.
I use Windows 7, mostly, though XP is also used.
I have a KVM, it accepts keyboard and mouse input, and is networked so that I can remotely input via mouse and keyboard. However, I wish to copy and paste text (even modifiers, such as alt, ctrl, and so forth).
The onscreen keyboard is fine for...you know, keyboarding, but I want to send keys (much like VBS does) through copy and paste.

At this time I've made a little VB script that lets me do this, but it has some extreme limitations, primarily in that it doesn't STOP once you get going. If the window looses focus, or it does something unexpected, bad things happen.

Imagine putting a line of commands that are meant to control a Windows computer, remotely, and it just control your terminal, because the window lost focus. I have no difficulty in giving the right window focus in the code, but a simple slip of the hand will break it. Ideally, I would only be sending those keystrokes to THAT window, regardless of what window is active.

I have been unable to find a way to do that through VBS, though perhaps it exists. I could simply loop, forcing that window to go active for each keystroke, but that doesn't ALWAYS work, as I sometimes need to use key combos, and I have no idea how I'd send an %{f4} one character at a time and still make it work.

So, finally, here's the question: How can I copy and paste test into a text field so that it ALWAYS goes to the window I want it to go to? Preferably it'll be usable in other windows (may have more than one instance open), should I want to do that, and it should be able to go a certain typing speed, as the application I use does crash if you send too much data at once (unclear how much is too much, but a single line is usually fine).

This isn't all that different from using a macro program, but I will be severely limited in what sort of application I can use. Scripts or java apps are about all I can get away with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You use `AppActivate` with `sendkeys`.

Comment: That's how I do it now, but there are some really negative flaws. The software I use to connect to the system has a very short buffer, so any string longer than (about) 40 characters crashes it. I've gone the direction of sendkeys mid(blah, 1, 1) and put in a sleep to allow the buffer to clear, but that's only good if you have no escaped characters. As soon as mid hits a brace it chokes. I've tried increasing the return characters permitted, but there seems to be no magic number that will get them all, without choking on some bracket, somewhere.

Comment: Ok, that seems odd. It doesn't choke unless there's a sleep in there to slow it down. It's kind of pointless without the sleep, but there's the problem.

Comment: Sleep  may have nothing to do with it. My tests are returning inconsistent results, with sometimes the script working, and sometimes it crashing. Mind, it's just H{@} being sent.